# How best to calculate sales tax in a marketplace (i.e., with multiple sellers)?

Tags: balanced-payments

We process orders for multiple sellers (a typical "marketplace" scenario). Are there APIs or services that correctly compute sales tax for our use case?

I simply want to provide the sellers' (1 or more) locations and the buyer's location, and receive the correct tax rate to assess on the corresponding line item.

Most offerings I've evaluated (TaxCloud is one) seem to fall down in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing a TaxCloud solution for a single-seller and multiple-buyer situation.  You can utilize TaxCloud to determine tax cost by creating an account for each seller in the marketplace, configuring nexus for each, then using the appropriate API key/ID pair to lookup tax on items based on the seller.

Unfortunately, this means that you'll have to make multiple calls if the shopping cart has items from multiple sellers.